# Why would a custom field using a completion action on a FH to increment field values by +1 continue to increment +1 if they filed out the form once?

Tags: custom-field, increment

I think this Question has Two-Maybe three parts to it that need solving or an answer.

Today we have form handler(s) with completion actions that will increment the value of a custom field (Pardot Forms Completed) by +1 every time a form connected to the form handler is submitted. We're seeing multiple issues where the custom field (Pardot Forms Completed) is continuing to increment, even though the form has only been submitted once. The form continues to submit on its own from the website (could be a bot-figuring that out) but if my prospect activity shows 3 form submissions the number should be 3 not 24 in the custom field (Pardot Forms Completed).

See Screen Shot Below. I am a Net New Prospect and filed out the form once: at 8:43am
[image: Pardot Screenshot of my Prospect Record and Activity.]

You see that it looks like I actually filed out the form more than once so the thought than as a net new prospect my custom field value would be 3 but it is 24 now.
[image: Pardot Screenshot of the Custom Field and values from the form handler.]